# Image from Resources via ResourceStream returns nil

Tags: delphi, resources, pascal

I've got a function that returns a TPicture object, from a resource stream, which loads PNGImage from a resource file.

```
function getImage(AName : string; lvl : integer): TPicture;
var Loader : TResourceStream;
    image : TPngImage;
begin
  Image := TPngImage.Create;
  try begin
        Loader := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, AName+'_l'+IntToStr(lvl) , RT_RCDATA);
        Loader.Position := 0;
        Image.LoadFromStream(Loader);
        result.Graphic := Image;
      end
  finally
     Image.Free;
     Loader.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with the code? The *image* object always **nil**, I searched the web for the answer, or any other way to load image from resources to TPicture, but found no answer that helped.

Comment: This code is totally broken. Result is never initialised. Your try/finally is wrong, because you free Loader irrespective of whether or not Loader is initialised. Pointless to set the position of the stream to 0 since it already is at that point in the code. The function certainly does not return `nil` since if `Result` was `nil` then there would be a runtime AV error. I'm voting to close the question

Comment: @lurker well that would be impossible

Comment: It's impossible. Either it's not nil or an exception is raised.

Comment: And also unnecessary "begin end" between "try finally" block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, your code is quite broken.  It should look more like this instead:

```
function getImage(AName : string; lvl : integer): TPicture;
var
  Loader : TResourceStream;
  image : TPngImage;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Image := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    Loader := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, AName+'_l'+IntToStr(lvl), RT_RCDATA);
    try
      Image.LoadFromStream(Loader);
    finally
      Loader.Free;
    end;
    Result := TPicture.Create;
    try
      Result.Graphic := Image;
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    Image.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then the caller can do this:

```
var
  Pic: TPicture;
begin
  Pic := getImage(...);
  try
    // use Pic as needed...
  finally
    Pic.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, it is generally not a good design choice to return a new object as a function result.  The caller should create the object and pass it into the function to be filled in, that way the caller can choose where the object comes from (for example, using the `TImage.Picture` property):

```
procedure getImage(AName : string; lvl : integer; APicture: TPicture);
var
  Loader : TResourceStream;
  image : TPngImage;
begin
  APicture.Assign(nil);
  Image := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    Loader := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, AName+'_l'+IntToStr(lvl), RT_RCDATA);
    try
      Image.LoadFromStream(Loader);
    finally
      Loader.Free;
    end;
    APicture.Graphic := Image;
  finally
    Image.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then the caller can do this:

```
var
  Pic: TPicture;
begin
  Pic := TPicture.Create;
  try
    getImage(..., Pic);
    // use Pic as needed...
  finally
    Pic.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or this:

```
begin
  getImage(..., Image1.Picture);
end;
```